# I can't figure out why my while loop is not giving the expected result ):

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, char, nested-loops

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am new to c++ and am practicing. I found code that writes two letter combinations with nested while loops and adds .com at the end. That code worked fine. In order to practice I wanted it to output a third combination but for some reason everytime I add the a third while loop the one in the middle only outputs {. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char letter1;
char letter2;
char letter3;

cout << "Three-letter domain names:" << endl;

letter1 = 'a';
while (letter1 <= 'z') {
    letter2 = 'a';
    while (letter2 <= 'z') {
        letter3 = 'a';
        ++letter2;
    }
    while (letter3 <= 'z') {
        cout << letter1 << letter2 << letter3 << ".com" << endl;
        ++letter3;
    }
    ++letter1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the third `while` be nested inside the second `while`?

Comment: Aside from what @Bathsheba already wrote, I'd recommend using for-loops instead for such a task (`for(char letter1 = 'a'; letter1 <= 'z'; letter1++)`). Would reduce your code by more than half its lines.

Comment: The entire `while (letter2 <= 'z')` loop has the same effect as `letter3 = 'a'; letter2 = 'z' + 1;`.

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) has questions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your third loop needs to be nested inside your second loop.

But there is an easier way which has the added bonus that it's also portable C++ (your assumption that the lower case letters are contiguous is the issue). Essentially this is a single integral counter converted to a base 26 radix:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr char alphabet[] = "abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    constexpr std::size_t radix = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < radix * radix * radix; ++i){
        std::cout
            << alphabet[i / radix / radix]
            << alphabet[(i / radix) % radix]
            << alphabet[i % radix]
            << ".com\n"
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third loop shall be a nested loop of the second while loop. That is there should be three nested loops.

Also as the variables letter1, letter2, and letter3 are not used outside the loops it is better to make them local variables of the loops. That is it is better to substitute the while loops for for loops.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Three-letter domain names:" << '\n';

    for ( char letter1 = 'a'; letter1 <= 'z'; ++letter1 ) 
    {
        for ( char letter2 = 'a'; letter2 <= 'z'; ++letter2 ) 
        {
            for ( char letter3 = 'a'; letter3 <= 'z'; ++letter3 ) 
            {
                std::cout << letter1 << letter2 << letter3 << ".com" << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
Three-letter domain names:
aaa.com
aab.com
aac.com
aad.com
aae.com
...
```

and so on.

Pay attention to that in general it is not necessary that letters follow each other without gaps in the used coding system.